# Using read.table to parse silly data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

I ran a rather large experiment and saved all the data to a csv file but the data seems to be in a... silly format. The simulation took days to run, and I'm not in a position to rerun it, so I'm curious if there's anything I can do in R to help me extract the data in the file's current form.

I don't seem able to attach a file with this question, so I'll explain the dilemma as best I can. The csv file is a string of data all contained in one column. Open in Excel, the first entry, A1, contains

```
[run number],"agent-preference","infection-rate","length-of-patch","incubation-rate","recovery-rate","init-infected","prop-move","total-pop","neighborhood-radius","move-distance","infective-radius","time-to-disease-spread","init-vaccinated","[step]","precision ((count turtles with [disease-status = 4]) / total-pop) 4"
```

All entries below this in cells A2-A1000 contains data in the same scrunched format, e.g.

```
2,"none","0.75","100","0.1","0.12","0.002","0","2000","10","1","2","0","0","222","0.9815"
```

That is, each *cell* contains all of the data in one long comma separated format (the silly format mentioned above). I thought that in order to get around this, I can use `read.table`, define my own column names (to get around the jumbled mess in A1), and then let commas denote separation, as follows:

```
my.df<-read.table("run_1.csv", header = F,   
                  col.names = c("run_number","agent_preference","infection_rate","length_of_patch",
                               "incubation_rate","recovery_rate","init_infected","prop_move","total_pop",
                               "neighborhood_radius","move_distance","infective_radius","time_to_disease_spread",
                               "init_vaccinated","step","outbreak_prop"),
                  sep = ",",    # define the separator between       columns
                  colClasses = c("character", "character", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor",
                                 "factor", "factor", "integer", "factor", "factor", "factor", "factor",
                                 "factor", "factor", "factor"),
                  fill = TRUE) # add blank fields if rows have unequal length
```

Note that I get around the funky format of A1 by specifying my own column names, and try to predefine classes of columns to help. Unfortunately, this doesn't work, and I end up getting (here using a single row of the data frame as an example):

```
>my.df[1,]
                                     run_number
1 2,"none","0.75","100","0.1","0.12","0.002","0","2000","10","1","2","0","0","222","0.9815"
  agent_preference infection_rate
1                                
  length_of_patch incubation_rate
1              NA                
  recovery_rate init_infected prop_move
1                                      
  total_pop neighborhood_radius
1        NA                    
  move_distance infective_radius
1                               
  time_to_disease_spread init_vaccinated
1                                       
  step outbreak_prop
1
```

If I want to look at the first entry in this row, I get

```
> my.df[1,1]
[1] "2,\"none\",\"0.75\",\"100\",\"0.1\",\"0.12\",\"0.002\",\"0\",\"2000\",\"10\",\"1\",\"2\",\"0\",\"0\",\"222\",\"0.9815\""
```

Which is wrong because (1) I want the individual entries to be the entire vector, rather than the first vector, and (2) I'm not sure where the dashes are being introduced...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `read.table(textConnection(gsub('"',"",read_lines("run_1.csv"))), sep=",", skip=1, fill = TRUE)`

Comment: Try `read.table("run_1.csv", header = TRUE, quote = "\"", sep = ",", col.names = ...)`.  You need to tell the function that your data is quoted.  I'd also take a second look at the column classes you've chosen as these don't seem to always make sense - i.e. why would infection rate be a factor?

Comment: FIRST of all what happens when you do `read.table("run_1.csv", skip = 1, fill = TRUE)`??

Comment: @Onyambu your first suggestion worked! Thank you. @ 27 ϕ 9 this produced an error: `Error in scan(file = file, what = what, sep = sep, quote = quote, dec = dec,  : 
  line 1 did not have 16 elements`. Nonetheless I did remove colClasses and that helped!

Comment: actually you should use `readLines` i dont know why i used `read_lines` ahah. Glad you figured it out